# Backing up encrypted bitlocker drive

Tags: linux, bitlocker, windows-backup

Is it possible to backup bitlocker drives without decrypting them? (just to have backup that is already encrypted?)

would it be possible to just dd (linux command) whole drive/parition into an image and store it, and then restore it if needed without problem?

Comment: It would only be possible if you were willing to image every sector of the drive when creating the image.

Comment: as a last resort it could consider it but, still searching for any other possible solutions